# Make text change depending on white slide is active in bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I need to change the text of something that is in a different column depening on which slide is active. I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong here.
HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>Recent News</h1>
            <p id="CarouselMessage">Hello World</p>     
        </div><!-- Column 6 -->
        <div class="col-sm-6"> 
        <div id="Carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">             
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#Carousel2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#Carousel2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
              </ol>
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" id="newscarousel" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <img src="news.png" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="news.png" alt="Chania">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="news.png" alt="Flower">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                      <img src="news.png" alt="Flower">
                    </div>
                </div><!-- Carousel inner -->
          </div><!-- CAROUSEL 2 -->            
        </div><!-- Column 6 -->
```

And here is the javascript to make the p tag with the ID CarouselMessage change depending on which slide is active.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var arrMessages = ["this is a test",  //set your messages here in an array
               "It worked for Image 2 class!",
               "It worked for Image 3 class!"]

var $msg = $("#CarouselMessage");
$('#Carousel2').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {

var text = "", 
     $active = $('div.active'),
     index = $('div.item').index($active); //check the index of active item

$msg.text(arrMessages[index]); //fetch the value from array based on the index of the item and display.

});
});
```

Comment: If it helps.. I have another carousel on my page. I don't know if that would be affecting anything though

Comment: `$('#Carousel2').on('slid.bs.carousel'`(the slid.bs... part) I don't think this is right, you need to have an event there, such as `click`.

Comment: What kind of even do you mean to make it so the text shows depending on what part of the carousel is active? I honestly am using this code here. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/axepx/) and cant figure out where my difference is or what I can do to fix it.

Comment: Ok nevermind, it's just a custom Bootstrap event.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help on this though.

Comment: If I move the p tag below the carousel. It will change to this is a test after I click one of the indicators but won't change after that